# Security - Run apps with other users

Tags: linux, security, fedora

OS: Fedora 14 i386

It's used as a ""normal desktop laptop"".

"USER A" - it's the mainly used user, i log in with GDM with it, etc.

Goal: I need a little more security - separate a few apps!

How: run 3 applications ( Transmission, Google Chrome, Wine ) with other users ( so not with "USER A" ). But when i'm logged in ( in GUI ) with "USER A", i need icons on he's the Desktop. E.g.: just one click ( without asking for password!! ) and Google Chrome starts with another user.

How exactly can i do this? - How can i "grant" "USER A" with permissions ( securely ) so that it doesn't needs a password, when running applications with "USER B", "USER C", etc.?

Are there any howtos/docs/links?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/231804/security-run-apps-with-other-users).

Comment: there are people visiting, watching only superuser. there are people visiting, wathing only serverfault. :( i don't understand why can't someone ask the same question on different forums, for different opinions. why? or there isn't any logical answer?

Comment: Update 2015: Chrome has since added a 'people' feature that lets you switch between profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use sudo to run a command as another user, eg. `sudo -u steve google-chrome`

However, a simpler solution to your problem (no users, no passwords) would be to run the browser pointing to a profile at another path eg. `google-chrome --user-data-dir=~/.config/google-chrome/Steve` http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

Comment: Running the browser as a separate user may have its advantages. It's a safer way to browse the internet. Linux users (like me) are used to feel invulnerable to viruses and malware. However if/when a virus strikes your carefully cherished desktop user profile will get screwed. Nobody can carefully estimate how likely for that to happen :)